# How to use gcc to compile a NASM-syntax .asm file?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, nasm

I have some `.asm` files that use the Intel Assembly format.

Is there a way I can compile these files with GCC/G++?

I know NASM and YASM have options to compile an `.asm` file, but can GCC/G++ do this by itself? With NASM, I use the `-fwin64` flag to make a 64-bit object file.

I use Windows 64 bit.

Comment: gcc -c myfile.s -o myfile.o

Comment: no, I mean how to run gcc -c *.asm?

Comment: Would you kindly show us the code you are trying to assemble by editing your question and adding it. I ask this because it really matters what assembler the asm file was written for. GCC usually handles `.s` and `.S` assembly files by passing them to GNU assembler. GNU assembler has different syntax than something like NASM assembler. If you provided your assembly code we could determine what it is you are really trying to do.

Comment: If you have a NASM assembly file then you assemble it with something like `nasm -f elf32 myfile.asm -o myfile.o` and then you can use _GCC_ to link it it to an executable with something like `gcc -m32 -o myfile myfile.o` . If 64-bit code replace `32` with `64`. GCC can not assemble a file meant for NASM.

Comment: ok, as I understand, gcc can not compile .asm file directly, and .asm should be compiled by nasm like that ,right?  what I mean is that if gcc could recgnize the .asm format and built it together?

Comment: @qbai What is “if gcc could recgnize the .asm format and built it together?” supposed to mean?

Comment: This question is in bad form.

Answer (score 2):

To compile `.asm` files to run with GCC you have to:

Make sure your `"_start"` label is `main`

Create a object of your `.asm` file with `nasm -f elf file.asm`

Link object file created with `gcc -m32 -o file file.o`*

Run with `./file`

*Link for a 32bit based program, to link 64bit based I think only `gcc -o file file.o` would do.

Comment: is it possible to do this without using nasm at all?

Comment: @bluejayke: not if your source file is written in NASM syntax.  NASM and YASM are the only two assemblers that understand NASM directives, macros, and syntax rules (like a bare label being an immediate instead of a memory operand).  GCC / GAS can't assemble NASM syntax.